# Java Telegram API library - did someone use it?

Tags: java, rpc, telegram

I use official Java library for Telegram API: https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api For tests I use code from Telegram Bot: https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-bot

There's a problem. When I try to authorize, library throws following exception:

```
Use test DC? (write test for test servers): yes
Using production servers
Loading fresh DC list...Exception in thread "Connection#2026789660" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown dispatcherId 'connection'
    at com.droidkit.actors.ActorSystem.actorOf(ActorSystem.java:121)
    at com.droidkit.actors.ActorSystem.actorOf(ActorSystem.java:93)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.transport.TransportTcpPool.<init>(TransportTcpPool.java:62)
    at org.telegram.mtproto.MTProto.<init>(MTProto.java:116)
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi$ConnectionThread.waitForDc(TelegramApi.java:895)
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi$ConnectionThread.run(TelegramApi.java:946)
Exception in thread "main" org.telegram.api.engine.TimeoutException
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCall(TelegramApi.java:364)
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCallNonAuth(TelegramApi.java:428)
    at org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi.doRpcCallNonAuth(TelegramApi.java:420)
    at org.telegram.bot.Application.login(Application.java:380)
    at org.telegram.bot.Application.main(Application.java:40)
```

I googled it and found out that it's a common old problem. So there's a question - can I use this library for my application that uses Telegram? Maybe someone found a way to fix this library?

Comment: Did you make it work? I am on it too with no success =S

Comment: I don't remember now did I solve this problem, but finally I gave up on that, there was some another problems. Telegram API is the library with very poor support from author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used older version of telegram-api, telegram-cl, telegram-mt and other depends to build Telegram S Edition, I success build it, but older version using old layer of telegram api so not supported new features.
You can find older versions on github like:
https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api/tree/da63cf65f7332d7a4f17626de9b00e9030ecf5cc

Comment: I recently create a project you can find and solve your problem with this, please take look at https://github.com/mokhtarabadi/telegram-s

Comment: Did you fixed something in telegram-api library or just used an old version and it worked? Don't you have a builded jar of telegram-api? I faced some problems with building.

Comment: I downloaded your telegram-s application, opened it in Android Studio and builded, but there's something strange and looks like a bug at the screen, and there're logs http://pastebin.com/t79WTe7k , look at them please.

Comment: I not changed anything only I used older versions, I know the issue and I now hard working to solve this.

Comment: I tried to build telegram-api from old sources, but it seems like I faced incompatible versions problems. Can you please tell me what version of telegram-api, mtproto, tl-core and actors did you use, or maybe you could give me your builded jar? Thanks

Comment: A few days ago i used these library and build Telegram S Edition: https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api/tree/da63cf65f7332d7a4f17626de9b00e9030ecf5cc and https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-mt/tree/9643457402a0d7f56debeecb0bdde596a8b8ae6a and https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-actors/tree/236679e724149a021596b3ce154d8f3240215695

Comment: What about tl-core library? Or the jar file in telegram-api "libs" dir is the same thing? Anyway thank you very much :)

Comment: for tl-core library you can use https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api/blob/da63cf65f7332d7a4f17626de9b00e9030ecf5cc/libs/tl-api-v11.jar

Comment: Thank you! Now I have another problem, but at least I'm little further now.
Now I got a `TimeoutException` when try:
`sentCode = api.doRpcCallNonAuth(new TLRequestAuthSendCode(phone, 0, my_app_id, my_app_hash, "en"));`

Comment: And finally I got an Exception when serializing the auth data (using code from telegram-bot). Seems like I should create an issue on github :)